# Search 802.1x enabled Aceess Point

Tags: wifi, 802.1x

In my campus, there are 10+ access points available.
Some of them are WPA2-PSK enabled while few are WEP and rest are 802.1x secured access points.

I want to connect only to those Access Point who are enabled by 802.1x.

Is there any way to differentiate such access points, when `iwlist scan` gives you combination of all available access points of all types ?